# Detailed Description of fields in xsd files in Customer Account Data

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

Customer Account Data API provides a list of xsd files but it doesn't provide a detailed description of all the fields in any xsd file. Some of the fields are obviously not trivial to understand at all. Could you please provide us with detailed description of each field in an xsd file?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute level details are mentioned in CAD docs.

If you have any question related to some specific XSDs, then please raise a support ticket.

Support link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/0010_submit_support_incidents

We will also update the ans in this post.

Thanks

Comment: When calling `getCustomerAccounts`, for an account, I noticed that the `balanceDate` is usually one to two hours after the time of the request with the timezone is taken into account already. why? Besides, what are `aggrAttemptDate` and `aggrSuccessDate`? They are not the time when the request is made.